# custom scroll javascript confused

Tags: javascript, scrollbar

I have a page set up like this:

```
<div id='container' style='width:670px;height:400px;overflow:hidden'>
<div id='content' style='width:2400px'>
there are images 200px by 200px, 12 across, 12 down
</div></div>
```

I then started to create a simple horizontal scrollbar like so:

HTML:

```
<div style='position:absolute;left:0px;top:400px;height:20px;width:670px;' id='scrollX_Controls'>
<div style='position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;width:50px;height:20px;' id='scrollX_Slider' onMouseDown="scrollX_Sliding='on';"></div></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
//myX = Mouse X, 
  if(scrollX_Sliding=='on')
  {
   document.getElementById('scrollX_Slider').style.left = (myX<=25)?0 + "px":(myX>=670-25)?670-50 + "px":myX -25 + "px"; // sets the slider position within the boundaries.
   document.all.container.scrollTop = (((myX-25)/(670))*document.all.content.offsetWidth); // supposed to convert ratio of slider over boundary to scrollLeft over offsetWidth
  }
```

Now supposedly everything works except for one thing that baffles me:
The scrollbar scrolls to the end of the content before it actually reaches the end of the boundary

When I tried to debug, I found that `document.all.content.offsetWidth` came up as 2400, which is correct, but the scrollLeft of container was only at 1731 when scrolled all the way to the right. also, I found that X (left) of `scrollX_Slider` was only at 483.2px

At first, I thought well this may be some stupid issue where it only has to scroll to 2200 to technically be the end because the width of a single image is 200px, but when I adjusted for this, I found that was not the case.

Why does it finish scrolling at 1731 when the width of the content is 2400?

Comment: Did you mean document.all.container.scrollLeft? (because you wrote scrollTop)

Comment: yes, thanks for catching that

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to forgive me; I changed your code a tad to make it easier for me to work with.

Anyway, I think I found the solution. I created a new variable, slider_x, to serve as a ratio for the mouse position; if slider_x = 0 then the slider's on the left, if it's 1 it's on the right.

Next, I multiplied this value by the difference between the content's offsetWidth and the container's offsetWidth. I believe you need to subtract the container's width from the contents in order to get the 'actual' width, which is what could have been wrong with your code.

Here's the code. I changed the IDs to lowercase as it is more semantic css-wise, but you can change it back if you need to.

```
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var content = document.getElementById('content');
var scrollx_controls = document.getElementById('scrollx_controls');

var width = scrollx_controls.offsetWidth;
var slider_x = myX / width;

document.getElementById('scrollx_slider').style.left = (slider_x*(width-50)) + "px";

var scroll_x = slider_x * (content.offsetWidth-container.offsetWidth);

container.scrollLeft = scroll_x;
```

If there's any problems with this code, or if you have any more questions, please tell me.

Comment: that makes a lot of sense. I will try that asap and let you know if it doesn't work. My guess is that you are right about finding the contents actual size, but why would 12 images at 200px width not be 2400? Thanks,